# MAPI works on one x64 System but not another

Tags: c#, mapi

I want to send E-Mails via MAPI. On one Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 it works fine. I tried the same Code on a Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 there I always get the following Exception:

> System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
>    at System.IntPtr.op_Explicit(IntPtr value)

The Code looks like this:

```
IntPtr GetRecipients(out int recipCount)
{
    recipCount = 0;
    if (m_recipients.Count == 0)
        return IntPtr.Zero;

    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MapiRecipDesc));
    IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(m_recipients.Count * size);

    int ptr = (int)intPtr;
    foreach (MapiRecipDesc mapiDesc in m_recipients)
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(mapiDesc, (IntPtr)ptr, false);
        ptr += size;
    }

    recipCount = m_recipients.Count;
    return intPtr;
}
```

This line:

> IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(m_recipients.Count * size);

is where the Error occurs.

size = 40 and m_recipients.Count = 1.

Why does it work on one System but not another?

Comment: Not so sure you identified the correct statement, the MarshalAlloc call has no IntPtr cast.  I'd need the exception stack trace to make the call.  But the casts to/from int are certainly not safe.  That can easily bomb on a 64-bit operating system.  A 32-bit program can have a 4 gigabyte address space, a 64-bit program will allocate at high addresses on recent Windows versions.  Use IntPtr.Add() instead.

Comment: You're right the problem was the line int ptr = (int)intPtr; I had to change it to long and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional debugging I saw that Hans Passant was right. The line that was the problem was:

> int ptr = (int)intPtr;

I had to change to `long` and it worked

> long ptr = (long)intPtr;